# User getting logged out of Argo CD UI with keycloak as OIDC provider

Tags: keycloak, argocd

We have installed Argo CD and integrated with keycloak as the OIDC provider following the steps - https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/user-management/keycloak/#integrating-keycloak-and-argocd

When we try to login to the Argo CD UI via keycloak, we see that the session is getting logged out in 5 mins. We did try to increase the Access token Lifespan to 15 mins but this still indeed did not increase the logout timeout of the UI and we observed that the user got logged out of the session within 15 mins. And this logout happens even though the user is doing some activity in the UI.

Any suggestions how we can increase the timeout so that the user doesn't get logged out quite frequently?